# how to combine two lists with the same structure in r

Tags: r

I have two lists,
say

```
list1<-list(a=c(0,1,2),b=c(3,4,5));
list2<-list(a=c(7,8,9),b=c(10,11,12));
```

how to get a combined list as

```
list(a= rbind(c(0,1,2),c(7,8,9)), b = rbind(c(3,4,5),c(10,11,12)) )
```

I can do it by for loops. Any other simpler way for this?

Thanks!

Comment: any reason you want to do this? Looks like you want to combine `$a` from list 1, 2, ... into a matrix which is going to act funny if your elements in `$a` from lists 1, 2, ... are different classes

Answer (score 10):

I think this would work in general:

```
l<-lapply(names(list1),function(x) rbind(list1[[x]],list2[[x]]))
names(l)<-names(list1)
```

But if you could guarantee the same order in each list, this would work

```
mapply(rbind,list1,list2,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# $a
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    1    2
# [2,]    7    8    9
# 
# $b
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    4    5
# [2,]   10   11   12
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `sapply` with `simplify=FALSE` gets you the elements named for free:

```
> sapply(names(list1),function(n){rbind(list1[[n]],list2[[n]])},simplify=FALSE)
$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    7    8    9

$b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    5
[2,]   10   11   12
```